# How i can Check button click is right or left in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, right-click

```
private void button_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButton.Right)
    {
    }
}
```

The Code is not working in WPF ... Help will be appreciated. Thanx ion advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF you can use the events `MouseDown` and `MouseUp`, which provide `MouseButtonEventArgs`. `Click` events are only raised for the main mouse button (depending on the system settings).

There are also the events `MouseLeftButtonDown`/`MouseLeftButtonUp` and `MouseRightButtonDown`/`MouseRightButtonUp`.

Answer (score 0):

The button click event will only be raised by the primary mouse button. However these can be swapped in system settings for right/left handed users.

If need to know whether it was the left or right button, then you can use the SystemParameters to obtain it.

```
private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SystemParameters.SwapButtons) 
        {
            // It's the right button.
        }
        else
        {
            // It's the standard left button.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use mousedown or mouseup events instead of click event, so you can detect from `MouseEventArgs e` like `if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)`